# iOS crash issue by EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics

I got some firebase log that telling some problem in my app please help me to understand what the problem for crash.

here the log...

> Exception name: EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 1245624
>
> libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw + 34136
>
> CoreFoundation +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 1245320
>
> Foundation -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 712744
>
> BaseBoard __40-[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:]_block_invoke +
>   231884
>
> libdispatch.dylib. _dispatch_client_callout + 4536
>
> libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 59372
>
> BaseBoard -[BSAction sendResponse:withCompletion:] + 231716
>
> UIKit -[UIHandleRemoteNotificationAction sendResponse:] + 6623704
>
> UIKit __91-[UIApplication
>   _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3.2881
>   + 2789148
>
> libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 4600
>
> libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 4536
>
> libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 23908
>
> CoreFoundation **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** +
>   907276
>
> CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 898040
>
> CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 37556
>
> GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 49556
>
> UIKit -[UIApplication _run] + 501752
>
> UIKit UIApplicationMain + 480560
>
> iosapp 4295996864 + 308672
>
> libdyld.dylib start + 17844

Comment: What are you doing to get this error?

Comment: I just put firebase SDK for tracking errors